# Calling .swf From HTML5

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML5 and am trying to get a simple example working of calling a .swf video file from an HTML button (or similar).

I have gotten this code so far but it doesn't seem to work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video src='test.swf' id='v' controls>
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    </br>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('v').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('v').pause()">Pause</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 9):

You can use embed tag:

SWF with background

```
<embed src="main.swf" width="550" height="400" />
```

SWF WITH transparent background

```
<embed src="main.swf" width="550" height="400" wmode="transparent" />
```

SWF WITH FLASHVARS

```
<embed src="main.swf" width="550" height="400" flashvars="id=hello world" wmode="transparent" />
```

To control the swf, you need to use External Interface functions.

Answer (score 5):

.swf is not a supported file format for the `<video>` element the only supported file formats are MPEG-4/H.264 Ogg/Theora and WebM/VP8 with suppport for individual formats varying across browsers.

For information on which browsers support what, refer to the excellent [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=video).

For a run down of the HTML5 video element I highly recommend [Operas Introduction to HTML5video](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/)

Comment: I came across this posting that seems to indicate that you can play .swf files in HTML5: 

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100520080940AAQXjxU

namely the "Best Answer":

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<object>
<param>
<embed> <- but this tag is new to HTML5

<object width='640' height='480' >
<param name='flash' value='flash.swf' />

<embed src='flash.swf' width='640' height='480' />
</object>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Is this not correct?

Comment: the embed tag is really 'new' to HTML5 its an old tag that was deprecated in HTML4 and then reintroduced in HTML5, much like some other tags like `<b>` and `<i>` you can indeed use that to play .swf files but again, you cant use the <video> tag to play swf.

Comment: Can you show me how to use the embed tag to play a .swf file?  I can't seem to get it working in the .html I have?

Comment: I've tried lots of examples from the web but nothing seems to work.  If anyone can provide a snippet of code that uses the embed tag with HTML and .swf files I'd appreciate it...