# Embed FLV videos in web page

Tags: html, media, flv

I have a user requirement to embed mp4 and flv in the website. I have not found any success with this. 
I realised that 
            `<video> </video>`
does not do the magic.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Your computer must have the codecs installed, the only browser that I believe have native codecs is GoogleChrome, for the other install kodecs to flv on your computer. For FLV you can try http://www.osflv.com/Download.html (with Flash)

Answer (score 3):

`HTML5` does not support .FLV files directly. You will need to convert the .FLV files or use a Flash Player. See the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html) for more info

You can, however, embed a .swf file, I believe. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733561/calling-swf-from-html5) for more information there.

As for `MP4` format, Firefox versions before v21 and Opera do not support it. Opera and older versions of Firefox both support WebM and Ogg Vorbis format for video, however.

Comment: Using a flash player is a good way to go. Can you show me? I'll appreciate that.

Comment: @Wale [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14398768/2756409) has some good information on that.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Chrome doesn't support WMV. Opera, Firefox and Chrome support Ogg Theora+Vorbis, while Chrome and Safari support MPEG-4 H.264+AAC.

```
<video controls>
  <source type="video/ogg; codecs=theora,vorbis" src="video.ogv">
  <source src="video.wmv">
  Your browser doesn't support video, you may download the
  video instead: <a href="video.ogv">Ogg</a>
</video>
```

The only browser that might be able to play WMV is Opera on Linux (if you happen to have the right GStreamer plugins installed). That's not very useful, so you should probably just not use WMV with  at all.

You might find this useful reading: Everything you need to know about HTML5 video and audio.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
  </object> 
</video>
```

read more about this : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Why You Should Use the MP4 File Format Instead of FLV : http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-camtasia-why-you-should-use-mp4.html

Comment: Your code requires codec installed, this is not a solution, edit your answer please.

Comment: 're almost there, but your answer is not the focus of the question yet.